# Model binds a dictionary fine on the way out but not on the way in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, collections, deserialization

I have this model that has a dictionary for contact info:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<ContactType, AccountContactInfo> ContactInfo { get; set; }

    public UserInfo()
    {
        ContactInfo = new Dictionary<ContactType, AccountContactInfo>();
    }
}
```

ContactType is an enum with enuerations such as Shipping, Billing, etc. AccountContactInfo is simple a viewmodel. plain string properties and nothing else.

Here is a sample portion of the view that reads the model. This UserInfo object is inside of the main model:

```
<div id="shipping-address" class="confirm-addresses">
    <h3>Shipping Address</h3>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].Street)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].Street)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].City)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].City)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].State)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].State, new { maxlength = 2})

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].Zip)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].Zip, new { maxlength = 5})

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].Phone1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].Phone1, new { maxlength = 10})

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].Phone2)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfo.ContactInfo[ContactType.Shipping].Phone2, new { maxlength = 10})

</div>
```

If this fully built model to the page, it displays perfectly fine. However when I send it back to the controller, it crashes with the following exception:

> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not
>   valid.

It appears to be related to the dictionary, and being that this is a recent change I've made to add the dictionary, Im sure that's it. Here is the stack trace if it helps: http://pastebin.com/8vyPWiFn

I set the break point right at the controller action but the debugger never gets to this point so I'm assuming it's breaking at some point during deserialization? I don't understand why this works on the way out to the page but not on the way back into the controller. The information that I'm sending in is the same information that was sent out.

Comment: What does your ACtion method look like ?

Comment: It doesn't doesn't do anything right now, but the signature just takes a single parameter which is the parent model of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah binding a Dictionary is a bit tricky, you just need to provide the correct element names, so for example:

```
@Html.Hidden("ContactInfo[0].Key", ContactType.Technical)
@Html.TextBox("ContactInfo[0].Value.Street", "Some street")

@Html.Hidden("ContactInfo[1].Key", ContactType.Billing)
@Html.TextBox("ContactInfo[1].Value.Street", "Some billing address")
```

You might also find [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) helpful.